# Where to buy my favorite magnetic chess set

Tags: equipment, chess-set

From childhood I have this favorite chess set which I use every day. The Black King and Queen no longer have the small white balls on their heads and the board is scratched in many places. I would like to buy a new one but cannot find it in any of the chess stores in Poland where I live. Can anyone point me to a seller of this kind of magnetic chess set anywhere in the world?

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I have already purchased a set like that thanks to Aric Fowler's answer, which is going to receive a 100 point bounty. Unfortunately, this new set is even more damanged than my old one. I have only managed to replace my damaged queen with a healthy one but I am still looking for another set, so this question is still open.

Comment: No, a google search of your image with the keywords "chess magnetic" in the shopping results gives no exact matches: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chess+magnetic&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsoLGKo_HNAhUMLsAKHVSxBNIQ_AUICigD&biw=1366&bih=667#spd=0

Comment: Try searching "magnetic chess set" on Amazon / Ebay. I looked on Amazon ( went 3 pages)  but couldn't find any pieces that looked your old set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

[Chess set](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/220056672/vintage-plastic-magnetic-chess-set-in?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_uk_en_gb_vintage-toy-game-low&utm_custom1=c2997ca4-4f98-4c00-ac37-6b4d0c50e447&gclid=Cj0KEQjw2ua8BRDeusOkl5qth4QBEiQA8BpQcChMV8LxoiyYsGF-VDqNYAEzCAyYKzE47qqJ_COiumUaAjzz8P8HAQ)

Vintage plastic magnetic chess set in carton box. 
Made in USSR, Latvia. 
Material: Plastic, magnet. 
Circa: 1980s. 
Has vintage condition. One white figurine has a crack, black king missing the top. 
Measurement: the box is 250 x 130 mm (9 7/8" x 5 1/8")

One problem is the black king in this set is also missing the white top, in which case you would have one incomplete piece. Also, the board has a black edge instead of white, however hopefully that isn't a problem.

[image: The closest match i can find]

Comment: One White Rook is badly damaged, which is much worse than the King missing his top. But this is exactly the same kind of chess set. The colors of the squares look different but it may be caused by unnatural lighting. I don't know. In any case, the pieces could well serve as a backup set. Thanks. Are you the seller?

Comment: no, i found this on the internet. You can replace the pieces in your current set with the ones from this set. That way you will have one complete set (apart from black king) and one incomplete set as a spare.

Comment: I have just brought this chess set home from the post office, shipped from Latvia. Thank you so much. I am awarding a 100 point bounty to your answer.

Comment: @user3456 you're welcome. To be honest, i get extremely sentimental about things and i hate it when they break. I'm glad you found a set to match yours :)

Comment: @user3456 did you award it? I haven't had any notifications in my inbox, sorry

Comment: I started the bounty with the sole intention of awarding it to you but the interface informed me that I need to wait 23 hours before I can do that, which is ridiculous considering that I explicitly selected the option to reward an existing answer. Let us wait till tomorrow.

Comment: @user3456 haha ok